# Safari 4.0 Open Links in New Tabs Not a new Window - Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, safari

Same question as [Make Safari open new links in existing windows as a tab, rather than a new window](https://superuser.com/questions/8859/make-safari-open-new-links-in-existing-windows-as-a-tab-rather-than-a-new-window/19195#19195) (for Mac OS X), how can I do this with Windows?

Example, every time I open a link in Google Reader a new window is created, I would like that window to be created as a tab and not a new window on Windows.  Can this be done?

Comment: It can be noted that adding the key TargetedClicksCreateTabs to `%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\Safari\Preferences\com.apple.Safari.plist` on Windows does not actually yield the desired results with Google Reader. External apps do respect the preference in the General section.

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do - when you click a link in Google Reader, it opens the item in the pane.. at least for me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, click the link while pressing `CTRL` key and it will open in a new tab.